# How To Use Ag-Grid In Angular 11

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use the Ag-Grid enterprise/community version in Angular 11
I am using angular 11 in my application, but not getting any hint from anywhere that, angular 11 is supported enterprise version of AG-GRID

Comment: See [Installing AG Grid Enterprise](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/licensing/#installing-ag-grid-enterprise) and [Angular Data Grid: Get Started with AG Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/getting-started/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. This is [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/getting-started/) to the documentation for the usage of ag-grid with angular.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the steps below

- Define the package json dependency for angular
  "ag-grid-angular": "latest",
  "ag-grid-community": "latest",
  "ag-grid-enterprise": "latest"
- If you have a liscence then define in main.ts
  LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("your key")
- <ag-grid-angular #yourGridReference id="yourGridID" class="ag-theme-alpine" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [rowData]="yourData" [columnDefs]="yourColumnDef">
- decorate your component code with the rowData and column definitions and you are good to go